# Forcing MySQL to use an non inclusive index to avoid table scan?

Tags: mysql, indexing

Background:
Huge table that have field ID AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, and another column timestamp that stores UNIX timestamp at the moment of the row insert operation. That timestamp column is not in any index and I cannot index it because of performance reasons.

Situation: We need to query this huge table for rows in past before a specific timestamp value; we could issue a `SELECT` statement and specify that condition in the `WHERE` clause, but that would lead to full table scan because the timestamp column is not indexed.

Suggestion: The nature of those two columns is both increment with each row inserted: AUTO INCREMENT column increases and timestamp column increases as well. I can devide the table into two equal num of rows each time and check the timestamp at each bounds and so on till I reach one row, then run a normal `SELECT` against it using that ID.

Problem with this solution: It's hard and it needs around 25 queries to complete that operation, and the number goes up as the table grow.

So the question: can MySQL be instructed to perform that operation in atomic context?

Comment: Well, that is sort of what a BTREE index does.

Comment: How large is the table in terms of rows and MB? And have you actually tested the performance of adding an index on the timestamp column?

Comment: Currently row count is 22M and I did create single column index for another column of that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvising on the idea of Drapp: Create a help table and a trigger that adds 1 row into this table for every 100 in the big one. This table would be equivalent to the following view but it will have an index on datetimeBasis.

```
CREATE VIEW HundredRowsStartKey AS
  SELECT 
      YourTimeStampColumn AS datetimeBasis,
      YourAutoIncColumn AS id
    FROM 
      YourTable
    WHERE
      YourAutoIncColumn % 100 = 0
;
```

Also added an improvement on the final query details, so it does a datetime scan on at most 200 rows of the big table. All the other matching rows and needed intermediate data are fetched using indexes:

- 2 searches on the help table
  (HundredRowsStartKey) and
- 3 range
  checks on the index of the big table.

Thus, the datetime range query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM 
    YourTable
  WHERE 
    YourTimeStampColumn BETWEEN "2011-02-12-01.00.23" 
                            AND "2011-03-15-12.00.00"
;
```

would become:

```
WITH starting AS
  SELECT
      max(id) AS startLow
    FROM
      HundredRowsStartKey h
    WHERE datetimeBasis <= "2011-02-12-01.00.23"
;

WITH ending AS
  SELECT
      max(id) AS endLow
    FROM
      HundredRowsStartKey h
    WHERE datetimeBasis <= "2011-03-15-12.00.00"
;

SELECT *
  FROM 
    YourTable
  WHERE
    -- these are guaranteed
    ( YourAutoIncColumn >= starting.startLow+100
    AND YourAutoIncColumn <= ending.endLow-1
    ) 
    -- and these 200 we have to filter
    OR
    ( ( YourAutoIncColumn BETWEEN starting.startLow 
                              AND starting.startLow+99
        OR
        YourAutoIncColumn BETWEEN ending.endLow 
                              AND ending.endLow+99
      )
      -- with the original filter
      AND
      ( YourTimeStampColumn BETWEEN "2011-02-12-01.00.23" 
                                AND "2011-03-15-12.00.00"
      )
    )
;
```

Minor edits may be needed to ensure that all edge cases are caught (like when starting datetime is before all recorded in the tables, etc.)

Comment: @To who was editing: sorry, i accidentally cancelled your edit.

Comment: @rahmanisback: I do NOT mean the View to be used. But a table that stores this View with the 200,000 rows. This will be quite fast.

Comment: @ypercube: I got your idea sir. I'm talkinb about the first SELECT
`SELECT
      max(id) AS startLow
    FROM
      HundredRowsStartKey h
    WHERE datetimeBasis <= "2011-02-12-01.00.23"
`
This would lead to scan that summary table "HundredRowsStartKey" of 200,000 rows.

Comment: @ypercube: oh well if you mean to create an index for the datetimeBasis column, in this case I agree it would serve very well!

Comment: Within the application level, I insert a row in the helper table if the ID inserted was dividable by 100 also.. no need for tokens as I mentioned above and no need to check this table everytime I insert a row in the master table. Thanks :)

Comment: thnx. You could also do that on the db level, with a trigger.

Comment: @ypercube: Correct, but for most of applications I saw I found that DB time is much precious than application time. So as long as the DB server doesn't have a full implementation of a solution, then it's better to rely on your client language capabilities. it's only an observation.

Answer (score 3):

I would try building a secondary table to your primary to at least act as a limiting basis of the query.  Prime the table with something like... (and obviously, put indexe by the datebasis)

```
create table DailyStartKey as 
SELECT 
      DATE( FROM_UNIXTIME( YourTimeStampColumn ) ) AS DateBasis,
      min( YourAutoIncColumn ) as FirstPKForDay
   from 
      YourTable
   group by 
      1
```

Then, you could prequery this table to get the minimum PK (and possibly the max if looking for a date range) in your query.  To keep it maintained without having to keep rebuilding it, I would add a trigger to your main table to try an insert into this DailyStartKey table if the date has NOT already been inserted yet.

Such query to utilize this might be...

```
select
      YourTable.*
   from 
      ( select FirstPKForDay
            from DailyStartKey
            where DateBasis = "2011-02-12" ) StartDate,
      ( select FirstPKForDay
            from DailyStartKey
            where DateBasis = "2011-02-25" ) LastDate,
      YourTable
   where
         YourTable.YourAutoIncColumn >= StartDate.FirstPKForDay
     and YourTable.YourAutoIncColumn <= LastDate.FirstPKForDay
```

EDIT to clarify another TRIGGER implementation.

To prevent the need to keep querying against the "DailyStartKey" table, you could create another table which is always and only one record with the last day the entry was created for. (or day/hour depending on the granularity you want).

Then, in your trigger to see if a new entry is needed, just

```
Select * from LastDateEntryTable where LastDate = CurrentDate
```

If one is already found, ignore.. otherwise, the trigger should do an insert into the daily key table and update the "LastDateEntryTable".

Comment: +1 Since we don't know the speed that your big table is populated, (100 rows per day?, 100 rows per minute?) and perhaps not even you know how fast this will happen in the future: You could have the trigger add a row in the DailyStartKey for every C (say 100) rows added at the big table (this could be 1000 or another constant). This way, if you want to search for a datetime range, you'll only have to first search the (renamed) HundredRowsStartKey and then search maximum 2C rows of the big table.

Comment: @DRapp: This is the most likely accepted suggestion so far, although the need to query the table `DailyStartKey` on each insert. Drapp you inspired me to run a CRON to signal a new day: say by a filesystem token, and whenever it's found, an insert into `DailyStartKey` is issued and remove this token, which if not found then I simply do nothing. 
But in term of merely DB solution, I didn't want to create any more indexes on the main table, but now you also inspired me to create a column in that main table that holds the absolute date value (will be same all day long) and this could be indexed.

Comment: Future answers are also welcome, I'm hoping to find a MySQL native technique for that issue ( I.E. making use of an index column when order on the other column is ensured to be the same )

Comment: @rahmanisback,  I've adjusted comment to handle trigger at the bottom.. Please review it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered partitioning your table based on date range? If you have the date range in your query & the table is partitioned the full table scan can be avoided. You could also partition your indexes too.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql_5.1_partitions.html